# How to recieve an image (file) with PHP that was submitted over a POST request

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I have a file: success.jpg

I would like to send this file over an HTTP POST request and have it land in a public directory on my server.

I have a simple HTML form and PHP processor that work if I'm uploading from the browser: php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

I'm trying to drop the use of a form altogether and just pass data over POST to a URL (e.g. myimageserver.com/public/upload.php).

It seems that I can use the PHP function move_uploaded_file and it even talks about using POST here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php but it doesn't provide the code which can receive and store a file that has been uploaded with POST.

Has anyone ever done something similar?

Comment: "it doesn't provide the code which can receive and store a file that has been uploaded with POST" — Yes it does! It's marked **Example #1**

Comment: "I'm trying to drop the use of a form altogether and just pass data over POST" — Where is the data going to come from if not from a form?

Comment: POST is a request method used to pass data, though it is used primarily with forms, it does not require the assistance of a form. The first example is not passing the file to the directory, the response is blank and the error log shows nothing.

Comment: I know what POST is. I'm asking you what method you are using to create a POST request if you aren't using a form. Are you sure the problem is with the PHP and not with the unspecified method you are making the request with? What do you mean by "the response is blank"? Example 1 doesn't output anything to the browser, it only deals with moving the file, so unless you add some more code, the response **should** be blank. If the error log shows nothing, have you tried turning up the PHP error logging level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couold read this example http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

which basically does something like this:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_dir = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk=1;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

The key is on the $_FILES global array.

To check if there were an error before appliying that example, you could use this example:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['uploadFile'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
/**
* Do the upload process mentioned above
**/
} else { 
/**
* There were an error
**/ 
}
```

Comment: Ok, I feel like this is it. Last question: Do I need to populate that global array or is that done for me when I upload a file? Trying it now...

Comment: 2014/10/31 13:01:10 [error] 18085#0: *1201 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploadFile in /usr/share/nginx/html/public/uploader.php on line 3
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploadFile in /usr/share/nginx/html/public/uploader.php on line 6" while reading response header from upstream, request: "POST /sandbox/shawney/shawneyuploadv1.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"

Comment: Two more things:

 - If your HTML file input is called "uploadFileInputName" then you can access through this using $_FILES['uploadFileInputName'], which in the example was "uploadFile".

 - The $_FILES will be populated if in your HTML form has the attribute <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> this is needed to send binary data to your server, otherwise the $_FILES will be empty

Comment: Ok, so then for the my purposes of bypassing the form and just uploading with a mobile app (or other POST method), that wouldn't be possible as I need an HTML form,right?

Comment: I just answered with another solution, hope it will be useful for you

Answer (score 4):

If you want to upload using a mobile app for example, you have to send via POST the base64 content of the image with the mimetype or the file extension of it, and then use something like this:

- Send the content base64 encoded and urlescaped.
- Receive the content and do base64 decode and then urldecode.

Then in PHP just do:

```
<?php
$base64decodedString = base64_decode(urldecode($_POST['yourInputString']));
$fileName = $_POST['fileNameString']; 
file_put_contents($fileName, $base64decodedString);
```

This will generate a file with the content

Comment: This is definitely good to know. I will see if I can implement based on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic HTML form to upload files

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="myFile" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Send" /> 
</form>
```

How to upload your file?

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/www/uploads/'; //physical address of uploads directory

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['myFile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
  echo "File was successfully uploaded.\n";
  /* Your file is uploaded into your server and you can do what ever you want with */
}else{
  echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
?>
```

Some details
- How to get the physical address of uploads directory?
Just create an index file into your upload dir and run this code

```
<?php echo getcwd();?>
```

It's done, if you need more details, just feel free to ask.

AGAIN THIS IS THE BASIC WAY.

Comment: Is it possible to bypass the form and send a HTTP POST request from something other than an HTML form (i.e. mobile app, formulated POST request with a browser extension https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fadvanced-rest-client%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo%3Fhl%3Den-US&ei=scJTVO7PD8OmNqOQg-gF&usg=AFQjCNEkroM42vfwzL0_5_3WgPLuFCnAZg&bvm=bv.78677474,d.eXY). It seems that the $_FILES array has to be defined.

Comment: 1- Sorry I didn't get your need, Do you want to auto upload file without using a HTML form?
2- $_FILES array will be defined as soon your form is sent.

Comment: Right, this is common practice for mobile development as it would require installing FTP or SSH into a mobile app just to upload images. Using HTTP POST uses what is built into the mobile browser/operating system already. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: As far as I know, modern mobile phones are using well done browsers. You are welcome :D